# Study the convergence of the series below

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone explain to me if this series converges, and what should I test it for in order to study it 
 The series is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2*2^n}$$

Comment: If you have a second question you would like answered, then you should post another question. Don't edit a question to be completely different especially after someone has volunteered to help you already.

Comment: i am sorry, i just am learning how to write questions but i will put it back to the original stat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is
$$
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n
$$
and you should recognize a convergent geometric series.

Comment: the expression under summation is a geometric series?

Comment: It is a special case of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$ with $0<a<1$.

Comment: what is the formula of the sum please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: So the common ration is 1/2 and i use the formula of the sum of a geometric series and then multiply it by 1/2, that is the convergence?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: why is the -1/2 ?

Comment: Because the geometric series begins at $n=0$ while your series begins with $n=1$.

Comment: i don't understand but thanks anyway

Comment: $-1+(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4+\ldots) = a+a^2+a^3+\ldots$

Comment: great thanks man

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2\cdot2^n} = \frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

Use the root test.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What is the root test?

Comment: You may also use the fact that you have a convergent geometric series.

Comment: If $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \lt 1$ the series converges.

Comment: what is the limit in the concrete series?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: so the limit is 1/2?